# What variables need to be controlled for in this causal graphical model?

Tags: causality, graphical-model, causal-diagram

I have the below graphical causal model. I thought that when we apply the intervention i.e. do calculus we get to the graph on the right - that is deleting arrows going into the treatment (drug). to be clear i want to see effect of drug on cancer.

[image]

However when i used R daggify and use the ggdag_adjustment_set it only highlights age as something to control for:
[image]

Why hasn't area been highlighted - is it because if i control for area it may lead to bias? What kind of variable is 'area' and do i need to control for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to isolate a causal effect, we need the causal effect to be "identifiable."

At a high level, assuming binary variables here, a causal effect is identifiable if we can express the treatment effect that we care about — in this case $P(Cancer(Drug = 1)) - P(Cancer(Drug = 0))$ — in terms of quantities computable from our observed data.

There are a few conditions that need to be satisfied for our causal effect to be identifiable, but since you're asking about "what should I control for," the one that is most relevant is **exchangeability/conditional exchangeability.** Formally, for your setting, we'd express this as $Cancer(Drug) \perp Drug \mid L$ — conditioned on some set of confounders $L$, there is no dependence between the counterfactual value of "Cancer" and the observed treatment "Drug."

"The hard part" is determining "what goes in $L$." Luckily, the "backdoor criterion" exists to determine which variables you need to control for in a given causal DAG in order to achieve (conditional) exchangeability. This criterion states that, given a causal DAG, you need to "block" all "paths" between treatment and outcome that aren't the treatment -> outcome arrow denoting the effect you're trying to estimate.

You can think of a path in a DAG as a chain of arrows (ignoring the direction for now). To block a path, there needs to be either a "collider" ($\rightarrow X \leftarrow$, where $X$ is some placeholder variable) that we are not conditioning on (+ one other condition that I'll omit for simplicity), or we need to condition on a non-collider ($\rightarrow X \rightarrow$ or $\leftarrow X \rightarrow$).

If you apply these conditions to your DAG, you'll see that, to achieve conditional exchangeability, we need to block the path $Drug \leftarrow Age \rightarrow Cancer$. Since $Age$ is a non-collider, we need to condition on it. We do not need to condition on $Area$, since it does not lie on a path between $Cancer$ and $Drug$. There may settings/specific designs where you might condition on $Area$, but for identifying the causal effect of $Drug$ on $Cancer$, there is no need.

**Further reading**

My summary of the backdoor criterion is derived from [these lecture notes](https://jean997.github.io/BIOST_881_causal_inference/slides_2023/2_dags_confounding.html#32) — slides 27-48 — which give a further overview "what do I condition on."

For further details, I'd recommend reading the first 3 chapters (approximately) of [What If?](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/) — it's a fairly approachable textbook on causal inference.

Answer (score 1):

### Blocking the single confounder path is enough in this case

I assume you would like to estimate the effect of 'Drug' on 'Cancer' from some observational data. Your depiction of the graph under an intervention is correct. By choosing an adjustment set, you effectively try to transform the observational (left) into the interventional graph (right) insofar as the effect of 'Drug' on 'Cancer' is concerned. You are right to observe that the intervention removes two paths, but in the adjustment set only seems to block one of them. This is because only the confounder path via 'Age' is relevant to the estimation of the effect of 'Drug' on 'Cancer'.

#### Controlling for 'Age' closes all backdoor paths

A backdoor path is any path regardless of direction that would remain between your source and target node if all outgoing edges from your source node were removed.
Such a path is closed when there is a collider on the path (not relevant for your setting), or if you control for one of the variables along the path.

In your case, there is an open backdoor path between 'Drug', 'Age', and 'Cancer', with 'Age' being what is called a "confounding" variable. You can close it by adjusting for 'Age'. Since there are no more backdoor paths, you are done!

#### Controlling for 'Area' is not necessary but it will not hurt either

'Area' is simply a cause of 'Drug' without a special name for its position, as far as I am aware of. It is not a descendant of 'Drug' and not involved in any backdoor paths. You could control for it, but do not need to given your graph.

Comment: Adjusting for "Area" might hurt - not in bias but in variance. Following Model 9 in [Crash Course in Good and Bad Controls](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r493.pdf) including such an instrument can hurt precision (make the uncertainty around the treatment effect estimation unnecessarily wider)

Comment: I agree that it could have some negative effects in finite sample settings, but those are of statistical, not causal, nature so I did not want to mix the two.